# Get System brightness level

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, screen-brightness

I have a WPF app running on windows 10 devices in which I am setting system's brightness based on value set in a progress bar and its vice versa. I am querying WmiMonitorBrightness to get the brightness levels. [Here is the link](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=236898) that I am using to do so.

This was working fine until we started to have power plans set in devices.Now, if I am in battery saver mode and I go to display settings, I can move brightness to max (which is still slightly low so as to support battery saver power plan). So System is aligning its brightness levels' values to power plan but my wmi query is returning me the values supported by the hardware. These values are now higher than values in system's display settings.

This is causing the brightness control to move to a different value than value set by user.

How can I get the brightness levels that are seen in system's display settings? Is there any api which can be used?